# How to Replace null with "-" using single line in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to Replace `null` with `-`  using single line in jQuery

For Example

```
    var obj={
        "Key1":null,
        "key2":"I have null",
        "key3":null

    }
```

Expected Output:

```
var obj={
    "Key1":"-",
    "key2":"I have null",
    "key3":"-"

}
```

Comment: remove semicolon from `"Key1":null;` or review the edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and check the value. with a recursive function with a closure over the iterating object.

```js
var iter = o => k => o[k] && typeof o[k] === 'object' && Object.keys(o[k]).forEach(iter(o[k])) || o[k] === null && (o[k] = '-'),
    object = { Key1: null, key2: "I have null", key3: { kje: "test", dfasfd: null, demo: "null demo" } }; 

Object.keys(object).forEach(iter(object));
console.log(object);
```

which basically resolves with ES5 in

```js
var object = { Key1: null, key2: "I have null", key3: { kje: "test", dfasfd: null, demo: "null demo" } }; 

Object.keys(object).forEach(function iter(o) {
    return function (k) {
        if (o[k] && typeof o[k] === 'object') {
            Object.keys(o[k]).forEach(iter(o[k]));
            return;
        }
        o[k] === null && (o[k] = '-');
    };
}(object));
console.log(object);
```

Comment: Object.keys want work with if we have object inside object  like   var object = { 
  "Key1": null, 
   "key2": "I have null", 
    "key3": {
     "kje":"test",
      "dfasfd":null,
      "demo":"null demo"
    }
    };

Comment: @PrakashMadhak, that is a different need with nested object. wait a minute.

Comment: thanks @nina Sccholz for help me but it's not prosible in single line i want in single line   like JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj).split(":null").join((':\"-"')));

Answer (score 0):

This one-line function will work:

```
function nullToDash(obj){for(e in obj){if(obj.hasOwnProperty(e) && obj[e]===null){obj[e]="-";}}}
```

Edit: Unminified above function for better understanding

```
function nullToDash(obj){
    for(e in obj){
        if(obj.hasOwnProperty(e) && obj[e]===null){
            obj[e]="-";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Even the version that has no line breaks isn't really "single line" in the sense of being one statement. You could make it shorter by removing the `return` statement, given that it is kind of redundant considering that you modify the object that was passed in.

Comment: Yes.. the `return` statement is actually redundant

Answer (score 0):

In one line, It would look something like

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj).split(":null").join((':\"-"')));
```

```js
var obj = {
  "Key1": null,
  "key2": "I have null",
  "key3": null
}

var obj1=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj).split(":null").join((':\"-"')));

console.log(obj1)
```

To make the code generic

```
$.each( obj, function( key, value ) {
 if (value == null) 
   value = "-";
});
```

Comment: This isn't very generic, in the sense that it will crash if either a key name or a value contains the string `":null"`.

Comment: To make it generic we will have to loop the object in $.each and replace every null value with '-'.